# Log Post Parameters sent to a website

Tags: http, utilities

Something I have always been interested in out of curiosity, is there a tool or utility that will allow me so log post parameters sent to a website? Not a personal website, any site on the web.

Reason for this, is that I want to be able to develop a .NET application without having to add the overhead of creating a WebBrowser object and then using the DOM to automate tasks on a website.

I also want to use it to test security of my localhost development server, as I don't have VS Team System.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Fiddler (http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) - it's quite good debugging proxy, which allows for deep inspection and modification of the traffic between your browser and the websites.